# How to show up all title and description in List.Accordion and List.Item with react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I'm developing a mobile app with `react-native-paper`, and I'm using `List` in `react-native-paper`.

I would like to show up whole message on the `List`.
In default, `List` omits the part of the message if the message is too long like the gif below.

https://gyazo.com/d60defc5f46b51408d68e793f9365172

I have already tried to change the parameters(head, middle, tail, and clip) of `titleEllipsizeMode`.
However, these parameters didn't work as I expected.

This is my code.

```
<List.Section theme={{ colors: { primary: 'black' }}}>
              <List.Accordion
                title='Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong title title title'
                expanded={this.state.expanded}
                onPress={this._handlePress}
              >
                <List.Item
                  title='Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong title title title'
                  expanded={this.state.expanded}
                  titleEllipsizeMode='tail'
                  titleStyle={{ fontSize: 10 }}
                />
              </List.Accordion>
            </List.Section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the list title should not be too long as it's against the design guidelines.
Normally if you need to have a subtext then it would move underneath it as in the picture below.
[Gmail-guidelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dx6L.png)

Comment: Also you could try on the List.Item titleStyle adding  numberOfLines={2} to wrap the text around in two lines.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to have control over the entire styling of the list title and even list item title is to pass a component to the title prop then style the component:

```
<List.Accordion title={<View><Text>Accordion title</Text></View>}>
   <List.Item title="item title"/>
</List.Accordion>
```

Then you can style the View & Text components

Comment: This does not work, the title prop accepts `Type: React.ReactNode` which would just be a string. Can't pass in a component.